# $watch is not defined in side a $compile(cutsom directive) but scope is available in the controller but not in the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to compile the directive with $compile method but the following error is occurring. I want a long listing lazy load with one time binding functionality with out iterating a entire array

[image: $watch is not defined or not a function]

The code is below:

```
app.directive('lazyData', function() {
return {
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.sample = 'sample';
    }],
    replace: true,
    template: '<span ng-bind="favoriteFruit">sample {{favoriteFruit}}      </span>'
}});

app.directive('lazyLoad', function($compile) {
return {
    scope: {
        pdata: "@pagenationData",
        options: "@options"
    },
    transclude: true,
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', function(scope, ele) {
        var pData = JSON.parse(scope.pdata);
        options = angular.extend({
                itemsPerPage: 10,
                buttons: false
            }, scope.options),
            compile = $compile;
        var loadMore = function() {
            console.log(options.itemsPerPage);
            scope.tmpArr = pData.splice(0, options.itemsPerPage);
            console.log(scope.tmpArr);
            for (var i = 0; i < options.itemsPerPage; i++) {
                ele.find("#pageNationData").append(compile('<lazy-data></lazy-data>')(scope.tmpArr[i]));
            }
        };
        ele.find('#loadMoreButton').on('click', loadMore);
    }],
    replace: true,
    template: [
        '<div>',
        '<div id="pageNationData"></div>',
        '<div id="loadMoreButton">LoadMore</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('')
};
});
```

Comment: Where are you using $compile?

Comment: you can use ngInfiniteScroll ...

Comment: compile = $compile;
        var loadMore = function() {
            console.log(options.itemsPerPage);
            scope.tmpArr = pData.splice(0, options.itemsPerPage);
            console.log(scope.tmpArr);
            for (var i = 0; i < options.itemsPerPage; i++) {
                ele.find("#pageNationData").append(compile('<lazy-data></lazy-data>')(scope.tmpArr[i]));